# Scala Breeze matrix outer product

Tags: scala, scala-breeze

I am aware that in Breeze it is possible to calculate the outer product between two vectors using the `*` operator and transposing one of them. I couldn’t find anything about matrices though. Do you have any suggestions?

The question about vectors [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41714610/scala-breeze-cartesian-product-of-vectors) doesn't answer my question.

Comment: With two matrices you can use the Kronecker product which is available in Breeze